# How to filter an array of objects based on a particular object?

Tags: javascript, json, object, filtering

I have this array of objects that is continuously being updated from a JSON file (The last index will always update daily to a new date). My goal is to use the last three indexes (last three days) of this array of objects and get the object literal from each of the objects. How can I do this?

**Array of Objects**

```
"actuals": [
    {
      "cases": 4,
      "deaths": 1,
      "newCases": 3,
      "newDeaths": 3,
      "date": "2020-01-22"
    },
    {
      "cases": 5,
      "deaths": 2,
      "newCases": 5,
      "newDeaths": 3,
      "date": "2020-01-23"
    },
    {
      "cases": 9,
      "deaths": 5,
      "newCases": 7,
      "newDeaths": 3,
      "date": "2020-01-24"
    },
    {
      "cases": 15,
      "deaths": 7,
      "newCases": 3,
      "newDeaths": 3,
      "date": "2020-01-25"
    },
    {
      "cases": 19,
      "deaths": 3,
      "newCases": 5,
      "newDeaths": 4,
      "date": "2020-01-26"
    },
]
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? "[In a javascript array, how do I get the last 5 elements, excluding the first element?](//stackoverflow.com/q/6473858/90527)", "[Extracting last n elements from array without disturbing original array](//stackoverflow.com/q/54024039/90527)"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [`Array.slice`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/slice) to get the last three items and [`Array.reduce`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce) to get the sum of their `newCases` property:

```js
const arr=[{cases:4,deaths:1,newCases:3,newDeaths:3,date:"2020-01-22"},{cases:5,deaths:2,newCases:5,newDeaths:3,date:"2020-01-23"},{cases:9,deaths:5,newCases:7,newDeaths:3,date:"2020-01-24"},{cases:15,deaths:7,newCases:3,newDeaths:3,date:"2020-01-25"},{cases:19,deaths:3,newCases:5,newDeaths:4,date:"2020-01-26"},{cases:26,deaths:3,newCases:6,newDeaths:5,date:"2020-01-27"},{cases:34,deaths:5,newCases:9,newDeaths:3,date:"2020-01-28"},{cases:56,deaths:6,newCases:14,newDeaths:5,date:"2020-01-29"}];

const lastThreeNewCases = arr.slice(-3)

const avg = lastThreeNewCases.reduce((a,b) => a+=b.newCases, 0) / 3;

console.log(avg)
```

Answer (score 2):

Just start a pointer at length - 3 and iterate 3 times and keep adding the
`actuals[ptr]["newCases"]`

```js
const actuals = [{ "cases": 4, "deaths": 1, "newCases": 3, "newDeaths": 3, "date": "2020-01-22" }, { "cases": 5, "deaths": 2, "newCases": 5, "newDeaths": 3, "date": "2020-01-23" }, { "cases": 9, "deaths": 5, "newCases": 7, "newDeaths": 3, "date": "2020-01-24" }, { "cases": 15, "deaths": 7, "newCases": 3, "newDeaths": 3, "date": "2020-01-25" }, { "cases": 19, "deaths": 3, "newCases": 5, "newDeaths": 4, "date": "2020-01-26" }, { "cases": 26, "deaths": 3, "newCases": 6, "newDeaths": 5, "date": "2020-01-27" }, { "cases": 34, "deaths": 5, "newCases": 9, "newDeaths": 3, "date": "2020-01-28" }, { "cases": 56, "deaths": 6, "newCases": 14, "newDeaths": 5, "date": "2020-01-29" },]

let actLength = actuals.length ;
let total = 0;
for ( let i = actLength - 3; i < actLength; i++) {
  total += actuals[i]["newCases"] 
}
console.log(`Average: ${total/3}`)
//return ( total / 3 )
```